# How to expand the smartphone screen to the secondary display (monitor)

Tags: android

There are A_activity (red screen) and  B_activity (Blue screen) in my app.

What I want here is a blue screen on the monitor and a red screen on the smartphone screen.

The point is two.

1. Is it possible to extend the smartphone display to a monitor instead of mirroring it? (use wireless)
2. Is it possible to display A_activity on a smartphone screen and B_activity on a monitor while using a single app?

Comment: Wrong site - this is unrelated to programming. Maybe consider [su]? Just read the guidelines first, and be sure to show your work, not just a set of requirements.